# c++ calling a function outside the class definition in a function in the class

Tags: c++, variables, scope

EDIT:
I updated the code, hopefully more concrete now. Basically I was trying to extract features using the dlib library. I need to use the hashtable vocab in the function get_features (which is inside the class definition), but I want to assign values to vocab before the getting to the function get_features, as indicated in the code, which does not work. The class feature_extractor is defined by dlib library. I'm new to both c++ and dlib, and I actually don't know how to frame my question better.

---

Now my code is of the following structure:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <dlib/svm_threaded.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace dlib;

/*
 * Read a vocabulary file and return a map of vocab
 * ex. vocab["word-1"] = 0, vocab["word+0"] = 1, vocab["word+1"] = 2
 */
std::map<std::string,int> getVocab() {

    std::map<std::string, int> vocab;
    std::vector<string> words;

    ifstream infile("filename");
    string line;
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        words.push_back(line);
    }
    int cnt = 0;
    for (auto w : words) {
        vocab[w] = cnt;
        cnt++;
        }
    return vocab;
    }

class feature_extractor {
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> sequence_type;

    std::map<std::string, int> vocab = getVocab(); // if put here, it does NOT work.

    void get_features (
        feature_setter& set_feature,
        const sequence_type& sentence,
        unsigned long position
    ) const
    {
    std::map<std::string, int> vocab = getVocab(); // if put here, it works.
    set_feature(vocab[sentence[position]]);
    }


}

int main() {
    // other stuff
    structural_sequence_segmentation_trainer<feature_extractor> trainer;
    sequence_segmenter<feature_extractor> segmenter = trainer.train(samples, segments);
    // other stuff

}
```

Is there a way that I can use the hashtable in the function get_features without calling getVocab inside get_features? That is, having a variable `vocab` assigned the value before the function get_features and use it inside the function.

I tried calling f1 in the class definition before f2 and assign the hashtable to a variable, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is this getting voted down?

Comment: @Rodger Why did you vote it up? Any good reasoning?

Comment: Yup, it's a good question. I don't know how to do that either. The code is presented, it will have a clear answer, etc.

Comment: Just a guess on the downvote(s), clarity/completeness of the question. The way this is worded it sounds like you're asking if there is a way to reap the result of a function without actually calling it. I suspect what you're really trying to do is reap the function `f1()` results *once*, then bring those into `f2()`, something a `member variable` of `nameOfClass` would likely assist with. You said, "I tried calling f1 in the class definition before f2" - *that* code attempt would probably be something we could help you with, and should be part of your question, not fantasy code as it is now.

Comment: @Rodger The _"presented code"_ doesn't even compile.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added the line of code, as indicated by the comments and will try what you have suggested

Comment: @Hai ok. *now* it make sense. I think you just need a modified default constructor..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hedging a bet I understand your problem, There are a number of ways you could do this. One of them is below:

1. Define an alternate default constructor.
2. In the member initialization list of said-same, initialize `vocab` from the result of `getVocab()`.

That's it. It would look something like this:

```
class feature_extractor {
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> sequence_type;

    std::map<std::string, int> vocab;

    // constructor added here.
    feature_extractor() : vocab(getVocab()) // <=== member initialized
    {
    }

    // ... rest of your code ...
};
```

The prior code will participate in move-semantics as well, which should alleviate unnecessary copying as well.

Alternatively, you could make the vocab object in `getVocab()` a *static* var, declare the function result as a reference-type (likely `const`), and only load the file initially if the static `vocab.empty()` is true. Such as:

```
std::map<std::string,int> const& getVocab()
{
    static std::map<std::string, int> vocab;

    if (vocab.empty())
    {
        std::vector<std::string> words;

        std::ifstream infile("filename");
        std::string line;
        while (getline(infile, line)) {
            words.push_back(line);
        }
        int cnt = 0;
        for (auto w : words) {
            vocab[w] = cnt;
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return vocab;
}
```

Doing that, *all* users of `getVocab()` would get the same object reference. Thread safety can become an issue, so additional work will be needed if that is the case, but hopefully you get the idea. You could also combine this with the prior methods and make the `vocab` member variable a const-reference rather than a concrete object. In that case, all extractors would share the same reference to the same static `vocab` in the body of `getVocab()`:

```
class feature_extractor {
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> sequence_type;

    std::map<std::string, int> const& vocab; // note: reference

    // constructor added here.
    feature_extractor() : vocab(getVocab()) // <=== member initialized
    {
    }

    // ... rest of your code ...
};
```

As I said, a number of ways to do this. Which one depends on what best fits your usage pattern.

Comment: Thanks for providing multiple solutions. I tried both methods. Somehow, I have to initialize the member inside the constructor: `feature_extractor() {vocab = getVocab();}` ... But it now works.

Comment: @Hai No problem. The syntax for using *member initialization* is shown in both examples I provided. I would suggest doing that, especially in the latter case, where it isn't a suggestion; it's mandatory (references must *always* be initialized). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to use the function getVocab to initialise the member of your class feature_extractor. You can do that in the constructor (as suggested by WhozCraig). You could also make the function getVocab part of the same class if they are logically related and if you only need it there so that it does not go into the global namespace. 
Like for instance:

```
class feature_extractor {

private:

    std::map<std::string, int> getVocab() {
        // your code
    }

public:
    typedef std::vector<std::string> sequence_type;

    std::map<std::string, int> vocab ; 

    feature_extractor() 
    {
        vocab = getVocab();
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks. I ultimately defined the function inside the class definition and also used the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand what are you inclined to do but you can declare your hash table outside of your functions as global variable which is not recommended.